# Best practice for extracting parts of string in java

Tags: java, string

I have an input string like `ABCDEFG` and have to output a string containing the 1st, 3rd and 6th positions of the input string: `ACF`. What is the best way to accomplish this, anything better than the obvious concatenation of the 3 one-char substrings?
Thanks!

UPDATE: thanks for the solutions, they are helpful! **Another related question**: what would the solution be if I need most of the input string, i.e. output string contains all characters but the 2nd: `ACDEFG`. Is `StringBuilder` + `charAt()` the fastest? And if my input string is long (100 chars) then it would be better to concatenate (using `StringBuilder`) the 1st char with the `substring(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substring method is time consuming method in addition to the fact it parses the string from the beginning each time it is called.
Try the chartAt method instead and append to a StringBuilder instead of concatenating in a String like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "ABCDEFGH";
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(s.charAt(0)).append(s.charAt(2)).append(s.charAt(5)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = "" + input.charAt(0) + input.charAt(2) + input.charAt(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String x = "ABCDEFG";
String result = String.format("%c%c%c", x.charAt(0), x.charAt(2), x.charAt(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a letter picking function, something like `charsAt` below:

```
String t = charsAt("ABCDEFG", 0, 2, 5); // Zero based indices

public String charsAt(String s, int... indices) {
    char[] chs = new char[indices.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chs.length; ++i) {
        chs[i] = s.charAt(indices[i]);
    }
    return new String(chs);
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but it would be more helpful to the OP if you stated your thinking behind this rather than just providing a code sample. :-)

Comment: @middaparka thanks. The question is whether the OP looks for better language means (I could not give) or a short notation to use repeatedly (my function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charAt(int)` method of `String` class which returns character of a String by given index. But it returns a `char` value.So you have to convert it to `String` using `Character.toString(char)` method.
You can do it like this:

```
String input = "ABCDEFG";

String result = Character.toString(input.charAt(0)) + 
                Character.toString(input.charAt(2)) + 
                 Character.toString(input.charAt(5));
```